# Windows Phone Toolkit is missing CustomMessageBox?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my project, i installed Toolkit via nuget, so i have it in the list of installed components:

```
Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls    2.0.5
```

However, i cant see/use CustomMessageBox

[image]

On the other side, i see it in some random project:
[image]

Whats up? They didnt update toolkit for ages + i have the latest version...

Comment: Are you talking about WP Toolkit or Coding4Fun toolkit? CustomMessageBox is in the WP Toolkit.

Comment: Yes. You have installed coding4fun toolkit and asking for a windows phone toolkit. How is it possible?

Comment: Somehow, my comment was deleted: the problem was with old version of Silverlight toolkit.

Comment: Which version of the WP/Silverlight Toolkit are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just messing around with WP Toolkit and Coding4Fun toolkit.